# How can I draw such image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need to such graph? I know the length of Ur, Ul and Uc, and I know the angles phi c and phi L. So first I need to draw vector Ur with length 0.5 on axis x, then to draw vector Ul with angle phi L, then to draw vector Uc with angle phi c and at the end to connect the beginning of Ur with the end of Uc. [image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! What you try so far? Where you stuck in your effort? It seems that for this sketch the package `tikz-3dplot` could be handy.

Answer (score 4):

You only need the `turn` key, which is built into Ti*k*Z. For your convenience I put the parameters in functions (without arguments), so to turn by `180+phic` you need, as explained on p. 144 of the pgf manual, the bit

```
-- ([turn]180+phic:uc)
```

The libraries are only added to make it more convenient to mark the angles and distances.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={ur=2;ul=3;uc=4;phil=40;phic=40;},
    >=stealth,ang/.style={draw, angle eccentricity=1.5,angle radius=0.6cm}]
 \path (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (ur,0) coordinate (x1) 
 -- ([xshift=ur*1cm]phil:ul)  coordinate (x2) 
 -- ([turn]180+phic:uc)  coordinate (x3);
  \draw[<->] (0,{1.2*max(ur,ul,uc)*1cm}) coordinate (y) |- 
  ({1.2*max(ur,ul,uc)*1cm},0) coordinate (x);
  \path[->] (O) edge["$u_l$"] (x1) (x1) edge["$u_r$"] (x2) 
    (x2) edge["$u_c$"] (x3) (O) edge["$u_\Sigma$"] (x3)
   pic ["$\varphi_l$",ang]{angle=x--x1--x2}
   pic ["$\varphi_c$",ang]{angle=x1--x2--x3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust it by changing the values in

```
declare function={ur=2;ul=3;uc=4;phil=40;phic=40;}
```

Of course, you can also use `turn` twice,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={ur=2;ul=3;uc=4;phil=40;phic=40;},
    >=stealth,ang/.style={draw, angle eccentricity=1.5,angle radius=0.6cm}]
 \path (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (ur,0) coordinate (x1) 
 -- ([turn]phil:ul)  coordinate (x2) 
 -- ([turn]180+phic:uc)  coordinate (x3);
  \draw[<->] (0,{1.2*max(ur,ul,uc)*1cm}) coordinate (y) |- 
  ({1.2*max(ur,ul,uc)*1cm},0) coordinate (x);
  \path[->] (O) edge["$u_l$"] (x1) (x1) edge["$u_r$"] (x2) 
    (x2) edge["$u_c$"] (x3) (O) edge["$u_\Sigma$"] (x3)
   pic ["$\varphi_l$",ang]{angle=x--x1--x2}
   pic ["$\varphi_c$",ang]{angle=x1--x2--x3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```